# How to delete and duplicate specific Google ad using Google Ads script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-ads-script

Now I'm trying to make script to delete and duplicate specific ads which I give below as `Ad ID`.

Before deleting the ads, copy it and duplicate it to under the same ads group which was belonging to.

For example, here's targeted Ad information.

targetAccountId:'123-456-7890'
campaignId:'1234567890'
adGroupId:'0987654321'
adId:'8901234567'

I want to delete adId:'8901234567' and duplicate it to under adGroupId.
Also, I will use MCC account.

Type of ad is "responsive video ads"
*here's a reference; [Support for Responsive Video Ads in Scripts](https://ads-developers.googleblog.com/2021/10/support-for-responsive-video-ads-in.html)

I wrote script as below.
However, everytime I got an error
"*Error: No more values at main (Code:23:8)*"

although ad adGroupId and adId is existing and active.

```
function main() {
  var targetAccountId = '123-456-7890'; // Account ID
  var campaignId = '1234567890'; // Campaign ID to be added
  var adGroupId = '0987654321'; // Ad group ID
  var adId = '8901234567'; // Ad ID

  // Select and iterate over accounts within the MCC.
  var accountIterator = AdsManagerApp.accounts()
    .withIds([targetAccountId])
    .get();

  while (accountIterator.hasNext()) {
    var account = accountIterator.next();
    AdsManagerApp.select(account); // Selecting the child account.

    // Log for clarity.
    Logger.log('Processing account: ' + account.getCustomerId());

    // Attempt to find and process the specific campaign, ad group, and ad.
    var campaign = AdsApp.campaigns()
      .withIds([campaignId])
      .get()
      .next();

    var adGroup = campaign.adGroups()
      .withIds([adGroupId])
      .get()
      .next();

    var adIterator = adGroup.ads()
      .withIds([adId])
      .get();

    if (adIterator.hasNext()) {
      var adToDuplicate = adIterator.next();
      // Ensure it's a responsive video ad before proceeding.
      if (adToDuplicate.getType() === 'VIDEO_AD') { // This type check might need to be adjusted.
        // Duplicate ad logic goes here. As an example:
        var newAdOperation = adGroup.newVideoAd().responsiveVideoAdBuilder()
          // Builder methods to replicate the ad's properties.
          // Note: Actual methods will vary based on the ad's specifics.
          .build();

        if (newAdOperation.isSuccessful()) {
          // Remove the original ad after successful duplication.
          adToDuplicate.remove();
          Logger.log('Ad duplicated and original ad removed for account ' + account.getCustomerId());
        } else {
          Logger.log('Failed to create duplicate ad for account ' + account.getCustomerId());
        }
      } else {
        Logger.log('The specified ad is not a responsive video ad for account ' + account.getCustomerId());
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('Ad not found in account ' + account.getCustomerId());
    }
  }
}
```